# Splitting a URL path in jQuery and getting a part of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, url, split

I need to split the path entered by the user and grab only certain part of it.
For e.g. if the use enters path as:

```
/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/abc.jpg
```

Then I want to display only `images/abc.jpg`.

I'm getting

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

error at the moment.

Here's my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();

    console.log($(imgPath).split('/'));

    //console.log(slicedPath);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath">
<button id="getData">Click</button>
```

Comment: `.val()` returns a string, not a DOM Element.  Asking jQuery to wrap it is not going to work.  Just use `imgPath.split('/')`

Comment: What are the criteria for getting the last part of it?  Are you looking for a certain word (i.e. "images") or are you after maybe a file and the immediate parent?

Comment: The last part should be just an image name followed by the image extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(imgPath)` will try to locate the element where `imgPath` is selector. As the Path entered by user is not correct selector, it'll throw error.
Example, if user entered `/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/abc.jpg` the selector will be `$('/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/abc.jpg')` which is not valid express, thus the error.

You may use RegEx to get the image path

```
imgPath.match(/images\/.*$/i)[0]
```

The regex will match `images/` followed by any number of characters. `match` returns an array, so using `[0]` will get the image path.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#getData').click(function() {
    var imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();

    console.log(imgPath.match(/images\/.*$/i)[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath" value="/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/abc.jpg">
<button id="getData">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming to want the last two path values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#getData').click(function(){
     imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();

 var theArray = imgPath.split('/');  // split path into parts

 // take the last two indexes to form short path
 var shortPath = theArray[theArray.length - 2] + '/' + 
                 theArray[theArray.length - 1];


      });
});
```

Comment: Or more concisely: `theArray.split(-2).join('/')`

Answer (score -1):

You should use `console.log(imgPath.split("/"))` instead of `console.log($(imgPath).split("/"))`.

Here `imgPath` is just a variable that stores the input value and not a dom element to be used as `$(imgPath)`.