# Spliting the URL path and getting only 2 parts of it

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, split

I need to split the path entered by the user and grab only certain part of it. For e.g. if the user enters path as:

/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/April/abc.jpg

I should get it as :

April/abc.jpg

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();

    console.log($(imgPath).split('/'));

    //console.log(slicedPath);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath">
<button id="getData">Click</button>
```

Comment: So basically you only want the filename and the parent folder?

Comment: It is hard to give a clear answer. With the example you provide even more questions. Do you mean only the path after images? Do you mean only the last two children?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a URL path in jQuery and getting a part of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533945/splitting-a-url-path-in-jquery-and-getting-a-part-of-it)

Comment: I didn't realize until after I answered that you already asked this exact same question. Why?

Comment: oh!..sorry, I think I missed it, somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` returns an array. After splitting, you can get any portion in that like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    var imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();

    var split = imgPath.split('/');
    
    var desiredPath = split[split.length-2] + "/" + split[split.length-1];
    
    console.log(desiredPath);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath">
<button id="getData">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `split`, it will split the data into an `array`. Then you can use `array[number]`, to get a specific value out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();
    var s = imgPath.split('/');
    var l = s.length - 1;
    console.log(s[(l - 1)] + "/" + s[l]);

    //console.log(slicedPath);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath">
<button id="getData">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pop to fetch values from last after split,

```js
str = '/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/April/abc.jpg';
var a = str.split('/');
second = a.pop();
first = a.pop();
url = first+"/"+second;
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT :**

You can have more optimized way as,

```js
str = '/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/April/abc.jpg';
    var a = str.split('/');
    arr = [];
    arr.push(a.pop(),a.pop());
    str = arr.reverse().join("/");
    console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Advantage :**

In this way, you can have more than two(if you want) from last side of url so its flexibility to achieve more than two parts.

I hope this helps.